# How to handle lots of libraries with a Vec2 class

Tags: c++, class, point, modularity

I am writing a program which is starting to get too big to compile individually.

Within the project, I have a number of 'modules' which I think I can take out to become their own library, and this will allow me to use those libraries in future projects.

A lot of these libraries however are dependant on some form of a simple 2D point class (float x, float y).

My issue is that I don't know how I should handle the Vec2 class within each library, do I write a simple Vec2 class within the library's namespace or should I force the user to install an additional shared library first?

I suspect the second suggestion is the ideal one however I would rather my libraries had no bloat to them as they will mostly include just a single .cpp + .h file.

Comment: Why not place the Vec2 class in a header and `#include` that header in every other library that depends on it? You can even compile that header into an object file so you don't have to compile it every time you compile your application.

Comment: any decent make system should only recompiling the bits that are needed to be recompiled. If this is really one program then compile as such. Only make libraries if you need to reuse code in different programs

Comment: This depends on the complexity of the `Vec2` class and related functionality and the amount of optimization you require for operations involving and whether you need to pass the values between libs+the exe. A simple `Vec2` class could be implemented as a header only library. If you require a high degree of optimization, the logic should be implemented header only or in a static lib. If you're using a shared lib, you need to make sure the abi of the shared lib remains compatible or ensure any abi break is detected, if you ever plan on updating the implementation lib...